# Cryengine crashes at loading CryRenderD3D11

Tags: cryengine

Starting the CryEngine Launcher, creating a new project runs a loading screen that always crashes on CryRenderD3D11.

How can i fix that?

The Editor.log file is:

```
BackupNameAttachment=" Build(184) 19 Mar 16 (17 04 53)"  -- used by backup system
Log Started at Sat Mar 19 17:04:53 2016
Built on Mar 15 2016 14:54:28
Running 64 bit Windows version
Executable: M:\Videogiochi\CryTek Engine\CRYENGINE Launcher\Crytek\CRYENGINE_5.0\bin\win_x64\Sandbox.exe
FileVersion: 5.0.0.184
ProductVersion: 5.0.0.184
Added MOD directory <%engineroot%> to CryPak
Added MOD directory <%engineroot%/engine> to CryPak

Total number of logical processors: 4
Number of available logical processors: 4
Total number of system cores: 2
Number of cores available to process: 2

Processor 0:
  CPU: Intel Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4150 CPU @ 3.50GHz
  Family: 6, Model: 12, Stepping: 3
  FPU: On-Chip
  3DNow!: not present
  MMX: not present
  SSE: present
  SSE2: present
  SSE3: present
  Serial number not present or disabled

Processor 1:
  CPU: Intel Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4150 CPU @ 3.50GHz
  Family: 6, Model: 12, Stepping: 3
  FPU: On-Chip
  3DNow!: not present
  MMX: not present
  SSE: present
  SSE2: present
  SSE3: present
  Serial number not present or disabled

[Error] [CVARS]: [DUPLICATE] CXConsole::AddCommand(): console command [hmd_recenter_pose] is already registered
Loading Config file system.cfg (m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\system.cfg)
<17:04:53> OnSysSpecChange(4)
<17:04:53> [Warning] Config file VeryHighSpec.cfg not found!
<17:04:53> Loading Config file %ENGINEROOT%/editor.cfg (m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\editor.cfg)
<17:04:53> [Warning] Config file game.cfg not found!
<17:04:53> Loading Config file project.cfg (project.cfg)
<17:04:53> GameDir: Assets
<17:04:53> Loading Config file game.cfg (assets\game.cfg)
<17:04:53> creating CVarGroups from directory 'assets/Config/CVarGroups' ...
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_full.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_full.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_gameeffects.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_gameeffects.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_light.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_light.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_objectdetail.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_objectdetail.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_particles.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_particles.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_physics.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_physics.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_postprocessing.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_postprocessing.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_quality.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_quality.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_shading.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_shading.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_shadows.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_shadows.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_sound.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_sound.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_texture.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_texture.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_textureresolution.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_textureresolution.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_volumetriceffects.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_volumetriceffects.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file assets/Config/CVarGroups/sys_spec_water.cfg (assets\config\cvargroups\sys_spec_water.cfg)
<17:04:53> creating CVarGroups from directory 'Engine/Config/CVarGroups' ...
<17:04:53> [Warning] <ThreadConfigInfo>: Active platform identifier string "pc" not found in config "config/engine_core.thread_config".
<17:04:53> [Warning] <ThreadConfigInfo>: Active platform identifier string "pc" not found in config "config/engine_sandbox.thread_config".
<17:04:53> Windows 10 64 bit (build 10.0.10586)
<17:04:53> User name: "Luca"
<17:04:53> System language: Italian
<17:04:53> Windows Directory: "C:\WINDOWS"
<17:04:53> Local time is 17:04:53 03/19/16, system running for 37 minutes
<17:04:53> 16323MB physical memory installed, 12072MB available, 134217727MB virtual memory installed, 26 percent of memory in use
<17:04:53> PageFile usage: 43MB, Working Set: 52MB, Peak PageFile usage: 43MB,
<17:04:53> Current display mode is 1600x1200x32, (Unknown graphics card)
<17:04:53> IBM enhanced (101/102-key) keyboard and 8+ button mouse installed
<17:04:53> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<17:04:53> [Warning] Config file %USER%/game.cfg not found!
<17:04:53> Loading Config file system.cfg (m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\system.cfg)
<17:04:53> OnSysSpecChange(4)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file VeryHighSpec.cfg (assets\config\veryhighspec.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file %ENGINEROOT%/editor.cfg (m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\editor.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file game.cfg (assets\game.cfg)
<17:04:53> Loading Config file project.cfg (project.cfg)
<17:04:53> [Warning] Config file user.cfg not found!
<17:04:53> Stream Engine Initialization
<17:04:53> GameName: CRYENGINE SDK Example
<17:04:53> BuildTime: Mar 15 2016 14:54:28
<17:04:53> [Warning] Editor only supports DX11. Switching to DX11 Renderer.
<17:04:53> Physics initialization
<17:04:54> Initializing CryPhysics...
<17:04:54> Initializing CryPhysics done, MemUsage=972Kb
<17:04:54> [Warning] Cannot open Pak file assets\localization\english_xml.pak
<17:04:54> Localized language content(english) not available or modified from the original installation.
<17:04:54> [Warning] Cannot open Pak file assets\localization\english.pak
<17:04:54> Localized language content(english) not available or modified from the original installation.
<17:04:54> [Warning] Cannot open Pak file assets\localization\english.pak
<17:04:54> Localized language content(english) not available or modified from the original installation.
<17:04:54> [Error] <Localization> No localization files found!
<17:04:54> <Audio>: AudioSystem initialization
<17:04:54> Initializing CryAudioSystem...
<17:04:54> Initializing CryAudioImplSDLMixer...
<17:04:54> <Audio> <0.231>: CryAudioImplSDLMixer loaded
<17:04:54> Initializing CryAudioImplSDLMixer done, MemUsage=5476Kb
<17:04:54> Initializing CryAudioSystem done, MemUsage=6128Kb
<17:04:54> Renderer initialization
<17:04:54> Initializing CryRenderD3D11...
<17:04:54> CRenderer sizeof(Vec2f16)=4 sizeof(Vec3f16)=8
<17:04:54> Initializing CryRenderD3D11 done, MemUsage=3804Kb
<17:04:54> Initializing Direct3D and creating game window:
<17:04:54> D3DX_SDK_VERSION = <UNDEFINED>
<17:04:54> Direct3D driver is creating...
<17:04:54> Crytek Direct3D driver version 2.00 (Mar 15 2016 <14:54:30>)
<17:04:54> Creating window called 'CRYENGINE SDK Example' (1280x720)
<17:04:54> [HMD] HMD Renderer not initialized - stereoOuput [0] hmdDevice [ null]
<17:04:54> Flushing pended shaders...
<17:04:54> Finished flushing pended shaders...
<17:04:54> System Shutdown
Closing PAK file: assets\textures.pak
Closing PAK file: m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\engine\engine.pak
Closing PAK file: m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\engine\shadercache.pak
Closing PAK file: m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\engine\shadercachestartup.pak
Closing PAK file: m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\engine\shaders.pak
Closing PAK file: m:\videogiochi\crytek engine\cryengine launcher\crytek\cryengine_5.0\engine\shadersbin.pak
```

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post your question like this in the future; you can just edit the original question.

Comment: Indeed, made a mistake in my multitab browser. You are right.

Comment: This still doesn't really show much about the *crash* though. Have you tried asking on CryTek's forums, or asking their support? This log seems to indicate that the D3D API initializes successfully and then just shuts down.

Comment: The Cryengine forum has some problems because of I can't post. I contacted them on a Slack community and they managed to find the solution. I posted it in order to share it with others that could have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATI Radeon 4800 HD Series GPU supports up to DirectX 10. Cryengine requires DirectX 11 minimum in order to work. So the GPU can't work with Cryengine